# Assign Actionbar to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm fairly new to Android App development, therefore i guess this question is pretty much basic.

I have created a new Activity called **ShareActivity** and its layout. Now I'd like to assign a newly created menu to the Activity. My App launches so far and the Share-Intent calls the correct Activity but the `ActionBar` doesn't appear like I've created it so far.

Comment: extend ActionBarActivity instead of activity

Comment: it's so basic that you can google thousand of examples. Please, use Google before post in here.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla thanks for emphasizing to use google! As i mentioned, i'm fairly new to Android therefore i wasn't aware of what i should have looked for

Comment: @SvenHolzinger here you have some info of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla its ok. Can we now commit, i don't/didn't know the therm i was looking for?! is this ok for both of us? Thx

Comment: @Satyavrat As far as i know, extending to ActionBarActivity is deprecated since SDK Version 22 or so! But i really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the `menu` to your activity `Override` the function `onCreateOptionsMenu` like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something basic that i really missed!! Thanks sir, your answer deserves an upvote! But i have no repution yet ..